# jQuery trigger events stack over time

Tags: javascript, triggers, stack, jquery

I have a generall question about define customer events and trigger then:

```
jQuery(document).on('btn.hover', function () {
    jQuery('.orange_bubble').hover(function () {
        jQuery(this).addClass('hover');
    }, function () {
        jQuery(this).removeClass('hover');
    });
});
```

Now i can call the trigger event to fire this event one time.

```
jQuery(document).trigger('btn.hover');
```

If i generate content over ajax or via js i need to get rebind the event on new elements:

so i trigger it again:

```
$.ajax{
   bla
   success: {
      jQuery(document).trigger('btn.hover');
    }
}
```

How can i do this without stacking the events. I have this problem right now.
I am useing some customer events and sometimes they have to reinitate on all elements, but just onetime and not stacking.

What is the bestpractice to firing events once time ? 
If they are set to some elements in the dom?

Thx for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover) is a shortcut for using [mouseenter](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [mouseleave](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) events, but one drawback is it cannot be used for registering delegated handlers, so instead of using [.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover) use the events directly.

So try

```
jQuery(document).on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        jQuery(this).addClass('hover');
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        jQuery(this).removeClass('hover');
    }
}, '.orange_bubble')
```

Comment: your answer is awesome, i write some trigger to this and it works perfect!

Answer (score 1):

First of all you don't have to rebind the event to newly added elements if you use event delegation.
From [JQuery page](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers

you could use something like:

```
$( "//container of .orange_bubble elements" ).on( "hover", ".orange_bubble", function() {
  //your content
});
```

This will also prevent you from "stacking" the events